# ggplot secondary axis wrong legend colours

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been trying to create a plot with a secondary axis, but as you can see underneath, R changes all the line colours in the legend to blue, not just the one for the secondary axis:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

prev <- data.frame(
            YEAR = seq(1990,1995),
            GP   = c(7,9,14,12,11,12),
            HOSPITAL = c(0,0,0,0,0.5,0.8)
)

d <- melt(prev, id.vars="YEAR")
names(d)[2] <- "Datasets"

prev2 <- data.frame(
            YEAR = seq(1990,1995),
            Datasets = rep("REFERRALS",6),
            value = c(0.5,0.9,1.2,3,7,11)
)

ggplot(d, aes(YEAR, value, linetype=Datasets), show.guide=FALSE) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid","dashed","solid")) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=seq(1990,1995,1)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=1991, col="darkgrey") +
  geom_vline(xintercept= 1994, col="darkgrey") +
  geom_line(data=prev2, aes(y=value), col="blue") +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis=sec_axis(~.*7,name="number of referrals")) +
  theme_bw() + xlab("\nYear") + ylab("Prevalence") +
  theme(legend.justification=c(.1,.9), legend.position=c(.05,.96),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(c(.5,.5,.5,.5), "cm"),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color="blue"))
```

[image: secondary axis]

Does anyone know how to get the line colours in the legend back to black for "GP" and "HOSPITAL"?

Comment: Your referrals data takes values between 0.5 and 11 and yet you've changed your secondary axis to run between 0 and 100. I assume you pre-transformed the data by dividing by 7 but perhaps you should make this more explicit to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control the color in the guide:

```
+ guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = "red")))
```

Here I use red for highlighting that this works for arbitrary colors. You want of course `color  = c("black", "black", "blue")`.

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: I don't want them all to be black though, they should represent the colours in the plot, i.e. GP, HOSPITAL = black, REFERRALS - blue

Comment: ah you were nearby there! `color=c("black","black","blue")` does the trick

Comment: if you edit your post, I'll accept it as the correct solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the order of your calls to geom_line. Like so:

```
ggplot(d, aes(YEAR, value, linetype=Datasets), show.guide=FALSE) +
  geom_line(data=prev2, aes(y=value), col="blue") +
  geom_line() +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid","dashed","solid")) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=seq(1990,1995,1)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=1991, col="darkgrey") +
  geom_vline(xintercept= 1994, col="darkgrey") +

  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis=sec_axis(~.*7,name="number of referrals")) +
  theme_bw() + xlab("\nYear") + ylab("Prevalence") +
  theme(legend.justification=c(.1,.9), legend.position=c(.05,.96),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(c(.5,.5,.5,.5), "cm"),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color="blue"))
```

Comment: that makes all of them black